# Can I mirror SQL server enterprise to standard?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to setup mirroring between 2 copies of SQL server. The primary box is SQL server enterprise edition.

Can I mirror it to a SQL server standard edition? The purpose is to save a metric ton of money.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366349.aspx/):

> The two partners, that is the principal server and mirror server, must be running the same edition of SQL Server. The witness, if any, can run on any edition of SQL Server that supports database mirroring.

That being said, it is possible to set it up as long as you use TSQL commands and not the GUI.  I would never recommend it, but it is possible, as long as you guarantee you're not using any Enterprise features.  More warnings [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ialonso/archive/2011/11/09/never-ever-set-up-a-database-mirroring-session-across-different-sql-server-editions-sku.aspx) and [HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldatabasemirroring/thread/979539fd-dfcd-4d6e-8f92-ca609a063deb//).

Last edit - apparently this has been completely blocked in SQL 2012.  Looks like you're out of luck.